# Which tools can turn scanned paper documents into searchable text pdf on Mac?

Tags: osx, pdf, ocr, text-search, scanning

I need to convert scanned documents into searchable text PDFs on a mac.

Adobe Acrobat can do this perfectly with its text recognition feature, but Acrobat is quite expensive when considering I only need this one feature. Are there any  alternative OCR tools that can do this? Quality of OCR results is important.

It does not need to be free, just lower cost than Adobe Acrobat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They say that [Abbyy](http://www.abbyy.com/) FineReader Pro is the leader of the pack.

Otherwise, two things:

• You get what you pay for

• It is a good idea to run tests on your documents

Answer (score 1):

[PDFpen](http://www.smilesoftware.com/PDFpen/) by *SmileOnMyMac* has [OCR](http://www.smilesoftware.com/PDFpen/ocr.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can convert a scanned document into a fully searchable PDF online for free: [www.sandwichpdf.com](http://www.sandwichpdf.com/).

The PDF will be OCRed and the resulting text will be included as searchable text layer in the PDF. Max. file size for upload is 10MB.

Adobe provides also a webservice [finereaderonline.com](http://finereaderonline.com/). But it is limited to 10 pages, I don't know how much the paid version costs.

Answer (score 0):

[Yunmai Document Recognition](http://www.yunmai.com/en/ocr_sdks/document_recognition.html) may be a good choice for you. As I know, Yunmai Technology is also very professional on OCR technology.

I always think about the recognition accuracy and recognition speed. The average time for recognition of a document less than 6 seconds. The recognition accuracy can reach 99%. It can convert documents into PDF, Word, Text format files.

I have tried before. It can be used on Mac. Maybe you can go http://ocr.ccyunmai.com/en/doc/ to have a try.